# How to apply a sentence-level LDA model using Gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda

Is it possible to apply a sentence-level LDA model using Gensim as proposed in Bao and Datta(2014)?  The paper [is here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.2014.1930).

The distinct feature is that it makes the "one topic per sentence assumption" (p.1376). This is different from other sentence-level methods, which typically allow each sentence to include multiple topics. "The most straightforward method is to treat each sentence as a document and apply the LDA model on the collection of sentences rather than documents." (P.1376). But, I think it is more reasonable to assume that one sentence deals with one topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run what Brody & Elhadad (2010) call [local-LDA](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1860000/1858121/p804-brody.pdf?ip=212.184.196.254&id=1858121&acc=OPEN&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&__acm__=1555353462_3ef0068d0053c86e7a68410f74f9a194) - just feeding your text data to LDA sentence by sentence - easily, if you split your documents into sentences. However, LDA will still give you more than one topic per sentence (by definition, you get values for all topics, although gensim has the `minimum_probabiliy` default of 0.01), which of course is not the same as the approach proposed by Bao & Datta.

However, the [supplemental material](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/mnsc.2014.1930) to the article by Bao & Datta (2014) contains a C or C++ (I assume, it doesn't say in the readme) `.exe` plus usage instructions in the materials. You could just run that from the command line, or write a [wrapper for Python](https://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html) (to make the output in gensim format would be icing on the cake) - if you do, please share your code, it might be helpful to others.

Comment: Is it hard to write a wrapper for Python? Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if I can convert the output to the gensim format, because I'd like to visualize the topics. Could you please give some more hint about how that can be done? Thank you!

Comment: It certainly isn't a five minute thing to customize, but you could take the tutorial I linked to as a starting point, understand whats going on and then maybe even adapt gensim's `dtmmodel` (which is a wrapper for David Blei's original DTM and DIM code). The question is whether you need to. If you just want to visualize results, you can just run the Bao & Datta program on your data, get that output and then analyse and visualize it in whatever program you want.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!